# I can't invite users to chat

Tags: support, chat

Today I found out that I have no option to invite someone to a specific room.  Apparently a when you look at a chat profile it should like

[image]

But when I view that profile I see

[image]

I have confirmed with other users that this is not a user script and they all have the invite option.  I am also missing the invite user option when you click on the avatar on the right side of chat.  Others see

[image]

But I see

[image]

Comment: What did you do to get yourself banned? :P

Comment: Why do you so desperately want to chat with me? You know I'm no fun ...

Comment: Do you really want to invite users to chat? :P

Comment: Ooops, I posted a dupe now :)

Comment: @user0042 Not 100% dupe as yours is about the room not showing whereas I have no invite period.

Comment: @NathanOliver Yes, you're right. Let's see if I can single handed reopen my question (I doubt so).

Comment: Nobody wants to talk to you.

Comment: At first glance I wondered if this was crossposted from Interpersonal Skills and we were going to have to advise you on being more outgoing.

Comment: @BJMyers Nah. I'm so outgoing I've gone from the real plane to the complex one.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well obviously chat doesn't like you today. I'm guessing something got screwy with your chat profile and it got out of sync with your parent account.

I've resynced your chat profile and you've confirmed that the option is available now.

Also, this option will not be available if you're trying to invite a user that is already in the rooms you are in. So for example, if you and rene were in the same chatrooms, you couldn't invite him to the rooms you were in together. If you were in another room that rene was not in, then you'd have the option to invite them to the room.