# How is the invitation combo filled (made visible) in a specific users chat profile?

Tags: support, chat

I recently wanted to invite a particular user to a chat room ([SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) in case that matters).

I just addressed that users chat profile as `https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/nnnnnnnn/username` and got this view:

[image]

To my surprise there's only the *The Ministry of Silly Hats* chatroom available in the invitation combobox (that's another room I'm frequently participating in).

I've been asking other users at SOCVR if they experience the same behavior, and the results confused me even more:

- 2 confirmed the same behavior as I'm experiencing (but with a different room offered for selection)
- 1 (and he's a RO) said they don't see that invitation combo at all
- The specific user isn't participating in that room (at least not frequently or currently), and isn't pingable (*@username*) there

So the question is:
What are the criteria for the selection list presented in the invitation combo box?

---

Here's the mentioned RO's screenshot:

[image]

---

Looks like this has been mistaken this as a dupe. The [RO's problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357421/i-cant-invite-users-to-chat) seemed to be specific, and a mod fixed it (so this question isn't a duplicate of the linked meta question).

**I still want to know what the criteria for filling the invitation combo box are.**

Comment: Bluefeet has a diamond and had been an awesome moderator on SO but they nowadays act in their capacity as an SE Community Manager. Not all diamonds are equal ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I can't invite users to chat](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357421/i-cant-invite-users-to-chat)

Comment: @Florian I've explicitely stated this isn't really a dupe of that question. See the last paragraph of my question. Nathan had a different problem, he wasn't able to see the invitation combo at all. I formerly had closed that question as a duplicate myself, but mistakenly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The list of rooms that appears is based on various conditions:

- The invitation option will only appear for a user if you and the other user are not currently in the same chatrooms. If you are both in the same rooms, then you have no option to invite them (because the system knows you two can already chat there).
- If a user has been invited to join a room but never joined said room, then that room is no longer available for them to be invited to. However, if the user joins the room, and then leaves it, it will appear again on the list. We have a check in place to exclude rooms that a user has already been invited to but didn't accept.

Then, there are the obvious restrictions, like the user is banned from chat, or doesn't have [the rep to chat](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/chat).

Comment: From a UX point of view, it would probably be better to have all the rooms the current user is in added to the list of possible rooms to invite the viewed user into. You can rely on the already existing POST response and `alert()` ([1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cokzu.png), [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z7XxZ.png)) to inform the user why the invite can't be sent.

Comment: @Makyen Possibly, but that'd be a [feature-request] for chat. Feel free to write it up as that.

Comment: Thanks, I think this was the information we've been lacking. Could well be it was me who tried to invite that user earlier (and forgot).